# Want to embed a unique value in source code for changes of a single file in an SVN repository

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I am building using [SVN](https://subversion.apache.org/) for source code control.  I am already using [SubWCRev](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-subwcrev.html) (part of [TortoiseSVN](https://tortoisesvn.net/)) to embed unique SVN project related values into my source code.

I now have the need to generate and embed a unique value that only changes if a certain file in the SVN project is modified.  But it is not apparent how to accomplish this.  As SVN normally keeps 1 version number for the entire project rather than 1 version number per file in that project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> SVN normally keeps 1 version number for the entire project rather than
>   1 version number per file in that project

Each file still has the revision at which it was changed in the repository. The number is used in the keyword substitution for `$Id` and `$Revision`.